# hibernate - prevent some properties from being fetched

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have a Director class which contains list of Movies and a Movie class which contains director object.

The problem is whenever I fetch a movie, it also fetches corresponding Director and as the result, it also returns list of movies directed by that director.

My question is how can I prevent list of movies from being fetched whenever I fetch a movie ?(I still want to fetch list of movies when I fetch a director alone)

here is my Director class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DIRECTOR")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Director {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "D_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LOCATION", nullable = false)
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "director_id")
    private List<Movie> movies;

    @Column(name = "POSITIONS")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Position positions;
    @Column(name = "PHOTO_URL")
    private String photoUrl;

    //setters and getters
}
```

and a sample returned JSON:

```
{
  "id": "christopher-nolan",
  "name": "Christopher Nolan",
  "location": "London, England, UK",
  "movies": [
    {
      "id": "inception",
      "title": "Inception",
      "rate": 8.8,
      "numberOfRates": 1470268,
      "categories": "ACTION",
      "director": "christopher-nolan",
      "duration": 123,
      "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/Ku3leEm3N7/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
      "description": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO."
    },
    {
      "id": "interstellar",
      "title": "Interstellar",
      "rate": 8.6,
      "numberOfRates": 930496,
      "categories": "ADVENTURE",
      "director": "christopher-nolan",
      "duration": 169,
      "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/tSqxSLMKg5/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
      "description": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival."
    },
    {
      "id": "the-dark-knight",
      "title": "The Dark Knight",
      "rate": 9,
      "numberOfRates": 1678434,
      "categories": "ACTION",
      "director": "christopher-nolan",
      "duration": 152,
      "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/SyC1yqkQ55/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
      "description": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice."
    },
    {
      "id": "the-dark-knight-rises",
      "title": "The Dark Knight Rises",
      "rate": 8.5,
      "numberOfRates": 1146075,
      "categories": "ACTION",
      "director": "christopher-nolan",
      "duration": 164,
      "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/UTo1oyUVDH/MV5BMTk4ODQzNDY3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODA0NTM4Nw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
      "description": "Eight years after the Joker's reign of anarchy, the Dark Knight, with the help of the enigmatic Selina, is forced from his imposed exile to save Gotham City, now on the edge of total annihilation, from the brutal guerrilla terrorist Bane."
    }
  ],
  "positions": "DIRECTOR",
  "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/xNYollZv1Y/MV5BNjE3NDQyOTYyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODcyODU2Mw%40%40._V1_UY317_CR7%2C0%2C214%2C317_AL_.jpg"
}
```

and my Movie class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVIE")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "RATE", nullable = false)
    private double rate;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_RATES", nullable = false)
    private int numberOfRates;
    @Column(name = "CATEGORIES")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Category categories;
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Director director;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "DURATION", nullable = false)
    private int duration;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "PHOTO_URL", nullable = false)
    private String photoUrl;
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

//setters and getters
}
```

and a sample returned JSON:

```
{
  "id": "interstellar",
  "title": "Interstellar",
  "rate": 8.6,
  "numberOfRates": 930496,
  "categories": "ADVENTURE",
  "director": {
    "id": "christopher-nolan",
    "name": "Christopher Nolan",
    "location": "London, England, UK",
    "movies": [
      {
        "id": "inception",
        "title": "Inception",
        "rate": 8.8,
        "numberOfRates": 1470268,
        "categories": "ACTION",
        "director": "christopher-nolan",
        "duration": 123,
        "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/Ku3leEm3N7/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
        "description": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO."
      },
      {
        "id": "interstellar",
        "title": "Interstellar",
        "rate": 8.6,
        "numberOfRates": 930496,
        "categories": "ADVENTURE",
        "director": "christopher-nolan",
        "duration": 169,
        "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/tSqxSLMKg5/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
        "description": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival."
      },
      {
        "id": "the-dark-knight",
        "title": "The Dark Knight",
        "rate": 9,
        "numberOfRates": 1678434,
        "categories": "ACTION",
        "director": "christopher-nolan",
        "duration": 152,
        "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/SyC1yqkQ55/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
        "description": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice."
      },
      {
        "id": "the-dark-knight-rises",
        "title": "The Dark Knight Rises",
        "rate": 8.5,
        "numberOfRates": 1146075,
        "categories": "ACTION",
        "director": "christopher-nolan",
        "duration": 164,
        "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/UTo1oyUVDH/MV5BMTk4ODQzNDY3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODA0NTM4Nw%40%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
        "description": "Eight years after the Joker's reign of anarchy, the Dark Knight, with the help of the enigmatic Selina, is forced from his imposed exile to save Gotham City, now on the edge of total annihilation, from the brutal guerrilla terrorist Bane."
      }
    ],
    "positions": "DIRECTOR",
    "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/xNYollZv1Y/MV5BNjE3NDQyOTYyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODcyODU2Mw%40%40._V1_UY317_CR7%2C0%2C214%2C317_AL_.jpg"
  },
  "duration": 169,
  "photoUrl": "http://cdn.persiangig.com/preview/tSqxSLMKg5/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE%40._V1_UX182_CR0%2C0%2C182%2C268_AL_.jpg",
  "description": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival."
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the fetch type of movies from Eager to Lazy.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: ir.yasharne.imdb.model.Director.movies, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: ir.yasharne.imdb.model.Director["movies"]);`

Comment: This problem occurs when you move out of your current session scope. Your session completes its transaction and leaves the session after closing it, the new session doesn't have your lazily loaded object in its scope, hence you get could not initialize proxy - no Session.

To solve this, move your code into one transaction on service layer.

Comment: It happens because your json mapper tries to map this collection but it is not initialized. I dont know with which json mapper you work with but you need to configure it so that it will skip non initialized associations (by checking Hibernate.isInitialized on the field)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you wrote `FetchType.EAGER` . Change it to `FetchType.LAZY` so it will lazy initialize that object and fetch only when it is necessary and you call it by invoking Director class methods.